# cookie disabled or private mode in chrome or firefox extension background request

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, fetch-api

I am creating a extension for Firefox or chrome like everliker I want to like my posts on my behalf with this extension.

Everliker does what I want but I want to write it because we can't use this extensions pro plan we can't purchase it (US boycotted us and google as well and the payment of everliker is base on google payment:|).

So I want to create it myself and it's working well but just one problem!!
when I want to like posts:

```
var r = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        "X-CSRFToken": '9CdUSqRg9E48Yzcrl1DJfsjYYI8fEeci',
        "X-Instagram-Ajax": "1",
        'Origin': 'https://www.instagram.com',
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
    },
    credentials: "include"
};
console.log(fetch(likeUrl, r, n).then(this._toJson))
```

I get this error:

[image]
this is the error if picture doesn't appear:

> Error
>
> This page could not be loaded. If you have cookies disabled in your
>   browser, or you are browsing in Private Mode, please try enabling
>   cookies or turning off Private Mode, and then retrying your action.

I don't know how should be headers or how should enable cookies with headers as the error referring to this!

I will appreciate any suggestion or help Thanks

Comment: Where do you get the CSRF token from? Do you understand how they work?

Comment: @Xan Yes I know, I get the token from page and also csrf-token for all pages and requests and posts doesn't change it's same for all requests!! I don't know why but this is..

Comment: Hello, i have the same issue, did you get any valid answer?

Comment: @KaanÖner I posted the solution in the next post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer it will solve with `chrome.webRequest.onBeforSendHeaders.addListener();`